# How to eval a string containing an equal symbol?

Tags: python, string, eval, equals-operator

I have some issues with the `eval` function. I have a list like, for example,

```
list1 = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]
```

and I would like to assign each value of a tuple to the first element:

```
for el in list1 :
    eval(el[0]) = el[1]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

You *could* do this:

```
exec('%s = %s' % el)
```

But don't. Really, don't. You don't need dynamic local variables, you need a dictionary:

```
my_dict = dict(list1)
```

Comment: +1 [Is Using eval In Python A Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `eval` works only on expressions. That would need `exec`. Still, he shouldn't do that :P

Comment: using dictionaries is best. That way you have the keys and the values together in a single variable and also you can access them separately using keys() and values() if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `eval` for that.

You can access local environment directly by calling the `vars` builtin.  Here's an example interactive session:

```
>>> list1 = [("a", 4), ("b", 8)]
>>> vars().update(dict(list1))
>>> a
4
>>> b
8
```

Here `vars()` returns the dict with local variable bindings.  Since it returns a pointer to the only instance (not a copy), you can modify it in place (`.update`).

Comment: While this is true, and does answer his question, you really shouldn't do that. Must better to just create a new dictionary for them.

Comment: According to the [`vars()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars): "Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`. Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored."