# How do I create lists out of dictionary, having same name as dictionary keys and same size as value of that key?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python, Suppose there is a dictionary named fruits:

```
fruits={
"apple":5,
"orange":7,
"mango":9
}
```

On reading the dictionary items, it should create 3 lists having same name as dictionary keys viz. apple, orange and mango and size of theses lists should be 5, 7 and 9 respectively.
The elements of these lists should be given from the user through console.

Comment: You need to post some code, show us what you have tried.

Comment: "it should create 3 lists having same name as dictionary keys". While it's certainly possible to do this in Python it's a _really_ dumb idea. If this is a  homework assignment you should seriously consider looking for a different teacher.

Comment: Suggest you read _[Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 3):

Got a solution for this-

```
fruit = {
    "apple": 5,
    "banana" : 10
}
for key in fruit.items():
    key = list(fruit.get(key)*[None])
```

This will serve my need.

Comment: Unfortunately this code results in a `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = { "apple":5, "orange":7, "mango":9 }
for k in d:
    temp = []
    for k2 in range(0,d[k]):
        print "enter the next "+str(k)+":"
        temp.append(raw_input())
    exec(str(k)+"="+str(temp))
```

but don't.
[How to eval a string containing an equal symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818318/how-to-eval-a-string-containing-an-equal-symbol)

Comment: It is dangerous to `exec` user input.

Comment: What's the most destructive input you could provide to these 7 lines of code?